# Looping a range of data to run only when a value in a column cell in column of data is 'Current'

Tags: excel, vba

I am a novice user. I have been asked by another department to amend a piece of code they already use. Their code uses a worksheet "Results" with a list of employees names in Column A, with their individual performance metrics recorded in each adjacent cell on the row. It then has a second worksheet "Scorecard" that is basically a template used for producing a pdf image. The current Macro determines if a name is in column A, copy the name to Cell E5 in the "Results" sheet which then pulls in the associated performance results for that person. It then creates a pdf image of the worksheet and saves the .pdf, then loops to the next name in column A and repeats the process until it reaches the last name. This works fine.

The problem is, that the code runs through every name in the column A, but not all names listed are current employees (they wish to retain historic data for other purposes). What they have asked, is for the macro to be amended to only run the process when the range value in column D is "Current". The other cells in this column are blank, so the code needs to find each reference to "Current" in the column.

I have tried various options I have found by searching info boards, but cannot get one to run correctly.  I have tried adding

```
 
For Each j In Range("D:D")
    If j.Value = "Current" Then
```

.. and then use some matching code, but I cannot work out how to correct the rest of the code so that it only draws the name from column A when 'Current" is in column D and then to run through only the rest of the process where "Current" appears adjacent to the name.

Can any one give me some help here? This is the working code I started with.

```
'Macro to draw an individual's results from the table, compile in the Scoreard worksheet
'then create a .pdf to be saved to system drive, then repeat for each individual in the table.
Dim c As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A5:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

For Each c In Rng

Worksheets("SCORECARD").Activate
Worksheets("SCORECARD").Range("E5").Value = c.Value

'Hide rows where metric category is blank for the individual
StartRow = 1
EndRow = 35
ColNum = 2
For i = StartRow To EndRow
If Cells(i, ColNum).Value = "HIDE" Then
Cells(i, ColNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next i

With Worksheets("SCORECARD").PageSetup

 '.Orientation = xlPortrait
 .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
 .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
 .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
 .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
 .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
 .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
End With

'Establish document save path and naming convention
Dim saveLocation As String
Dim detail As String
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim FileName As String
saveLocation = "H:\"

FileName = Worksheets("SCORECARD").Range("E7")
Set Rng1 = Sheets("SCORECARD").Range("A1:M35")

'Save a range as PDF
Rng1.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
FileName:=saveLocation & FileName & ".pdf"
Rows("1:35").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Next
End

End Sub
```

Thanks for taking the time to read to here and thank you for any advice.

Comment: Could you explain *it only draws the name from column A when 'Current" is in column D and then to run through only the rest of the process where "Current" appears adjacent to the name* using simple words?

Comment: What I need the code to do, is systematically run down the list of names in column A and determine if the word 'Current' appears in column D on a row with a name. If the word does appear, then I need the code to get the name corresponding to the column A cell, for that column D row that has the word, then add the column A name to cell E 5 on the second worksheet and then run the create pdf process. The process needs to run for each name in A that has 'Current" in D. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```vb
'Macro to draw an individual's results from the table, compile in the Scoreard worksheet
'then create a .pdf to be saved to system drive, then repeat for each individual in the table.
Sub Tester()
    Const COL_HIDE_FLAG As Long = 2
    Const FLDR_EXPORT As String = "H:\"
    Const RNG_EXPORT As String = "A1:M35"
    
    Dim c As Range, wsRes As Worksheet, wsSC As Worksheet, i As Long
    
    Set wsSC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SCORECARD")
    Set wsRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RESULTS")
    
    With wsSC.PageSetup 'no need to repeat this in your loop?
        '.Orientation = xlPortrait
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
    End With
    
    For Each c In wsRes.Range("A5:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        If LCase(Trim(c.EntireRow.Columns("D").Value)) = "current" Then 'only if current
            wsSC.Range("E5").Value = c.Value
            'Hide/unhide rows according to flag column
            For i = 1 To 35
                wsSC.Rows(i).Hidden = wsSC.Cells(i, COL_HIDE_FLAG).Value = "HIDE"
            Next i
            
            wsSC.Range(RNG_EXPORT).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                FileName:=FLDR_EXPORT & wsSC.Range("E7").Value & ".pdf"
        End If 'current
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Do I replace the 'For each c in Rng' in my existing code with your code? I tried that it nothing seems to happen.

Comment: See updated full code above.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, that does not seem to work for me. It seems to run the code, but nothing is produced at the end.

Comment: You'll need to step through the code as it runs and debug - I can't do that without your data.

Comment: I appreciate your help so far. This has helped me learn a lot, and I am sure I will get it to work. Thank you for your help and persistence. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: I can help troubleshoot if you're willing to share a (suitably redacted) copy of your workbook.